# Python Dictionary always returning the same value for any key

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I am indexing a huge text file into a dictionary containing the line numbers of each word in the file. The following code is what I have:

```
i = {}                               # The dictionary

with open("infl2.txt", "r") as f:
    for index, line in enumerate(f): # step through each line
        line = line.lower()          # for case insensitive key matching later on
        if index == 21:              # Print part of the dictionary for debug
            print i
        for w in line.split():       # Split line into words and iterate
            i[w] = index             # Add word to dictionary with line number as value


# TESTING
s = 'aa'
index = i[s]
print s + " -> " + str(index)
print len(i)
```

Output:

```
{'aa': 1, 'adhs': 12, 'ac': 9, 'ab': 4, 'ad': 11, 'afaik': 17, 'ai': 19, 'afps': 18, 'adrs': 15, 'as': 0, 'abcs': 5, 'aases': 3, 'aids': 20, 'abc': 5, 'abd': 6, 'ads': 11, 'adp': 13, 'aarp': 2, 'abm': 8, 'acth': 10, 'abs': 4, 'abls': 7, 'afp': 18, 'adh': 12, 'abds': 6, 'aec': 16, 'aidses': 20, 'adps': 14, 'adr': 15, 'a': 0, 'aecs': 16, 'adpses': 14, 'acths': 10, 'ais': 19, 'acs': 9, 'ablses': 7, 'aarps': 2, 'afaiks': 17, 'aas': 3, 'abms': 8}
aa -> 112505
252362
```

As you can see, 'aa' should return the value `1` (seen in the dump o' twenty in the first line of the output). However, it returns `112505`, which is the `file length (in lines) - 1`. No matter what key I test with, it always returns `112505`.

I have no idea why this happens, so I'd be grateful for a helping hand.

Comment: You do `i[w] = index`, index is the current line number. So of course all words in the dictionary are set to the last line number after doing that for all words of all lines.

Comment: Each value in the dictionary will be the last line on which that word occurs.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich yes if all the words are in the last line.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich  - Huh?  If a word does not appear on the last line /n/, how does i[<word>] == n?

Comment: @BadZen: I'm assuming they all occur on each line, because that's how you get that "No matter what key I test with, it always returns 112505."

Comment: Important to say that, however.  Your first comment made it sound like you thought it was a code and not data error.   In any case, the program works just fine for me, with made-up data.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Cheers mate, that solved it. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, derp. The file I was reading from was faulty and contained a copy of itself on the very last line, excluding newlines. Hence all values pointed to the same line after the last line was processed. The minus 1 comes from the fact that the first line is indexed as 0.

Comment: that's really bad luck!!

Comment: Yeah it's an english dictionary I got on github called AGID. It appears the author made a mistake, as there's really no reason for it and nothing in the readme about it either.